# scipy: minimize vs. minimize.scalar; return F versus return F**2; shouldnt make a difference?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I just found a behavior which I cannot explain. Do I miss something ?

I have an implicit function:

```
def my_cost_fun(x,a,b,c):
    # x is a scalar; all variables are provided as numpy arrays
    F = some_fun(x,a,b,c) - x
    return F
```

I do minimize the function using:

- `optimize.fsolve(my_cost_fun,0.2,args = (a,b,c))`
- `optimize.brentq(my_cost_fun,-0.2,0.2,args = (a,b,c))`

Or by the mimimize function:

- `optimize.minimize(my_cost_fun,0.2,args = (a,b,c),method = 'L-BFGS-B',bounds=((0,a),)`

The strange thing is:

- If I use `return F`

  - brent_q method and fsolve do give the same result and `%timeit` measures the fastest loop with ~ 250 µs
  - L-BFGS-B (and SLSQP and TNC) does not change `x0` at all and provides a wrong result
- If I use `return F**2`:

  - fsolve returns the right solution but converges slowly; 1.2 ms for the fastest loop
  - L-BFGS-B returns the right solution but converges slowly: 1.5 ms for the fastest loop

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Can you post a definition of `some_fun(x,a,b,c)` that reproduces the behavior you are reporting?

Comment: I will do so, but I need a little bit of time.

Comment: Here is one possible explaination of why L-BFGS-B is not working when you use `return F`.  If the value of `F` can be negative, then `optmize.minimize` will try to find that value.  `minimize` isn't necessarily finding a root, it's finding the minimum.  If you return `F**2` instead, since for real-valued functions `F**2` will always be positive, _minima_ of `F**2` will happen at `F`=0, i.e. the minima will be the roots.  I still don't know why the timing is so different, but would be curious if the form of your `some_fun()` could explain it if you get a chance.

Comment: Of course! Thank you a lot for this eye opener

Comment: I will try different solvers from openopt and pygmo. If this behaviour persists, I will re-evaluate my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments:

Here is one possible explaination of why L-BFGS-B is not working when you use `return F`: If the value of `F` can be negative, then optmize.minimize will try to find the most negative value it can. `minimize` isn't necessarily finding a root, it's finding the minimum. If you return `F**2` instead, since for real-valued functions `F**2` will always be positive, minima of `F**2` will happen at F=0, i.e. the minima will be the roots.

This doesn't explain your timing issue, but that may be of secondary concern.  I would still be curious to study the timing with your particular `some_fun(x,a,b,c)` if you get a chance to post a definition.

Comment: I will post the function via codepaste.net (In the evening (GMT+1))